# How to get Tier price html on product listing page in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, tierprice, product-listing

I want show default tier price in product listing page which we can see on product detail page.

> ex. Buy 5 for £47.00 each and save 6%

I can get using of **$product->getTierPrice();** in product listing page but it could be better if i can get using **tier_prices.phtml** via block or any other method.

Please any give any suggestion

Comment: You need to create he html on listing page by getting information of product.

Comment: i understand but i want use default tier_price.phtml using xml  or block

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
if($_product->getTierPrice()){
    $tier_price = $_product->getTierPrice();
    foreach ($tier_price as $key => $value) {
        $qty = (int)$value['price_qty'];
        $price = $value['price'];
        $formattedPrice = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($price, 2), true, false);
        $savePercentageFormat = ceil(100 - ( (100 / $_product->getPrice())* $value['price']) ) ."%";

        echo "Buy $qty for ".$formattedPrice." each and save ".$savePercentageFormat;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i achieve using of tier_prices.phtml ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code in product listing page :

```
$tier_price = $_product->getTierPrice();

if(count($tier_price) > 0){
foreach($tier_price as $pirces){
    foreach ( array_reverse($pirces) as $key => $value ) {
        if($key == "price"){
            $tierprice = number_format($value, 2, '.', '');
            echo $tierprice;
        }
```

**hope its work for you**

Comment: i don't want via $_product->getTierPrice() but its working by the way